# Sending data from detail view to a form

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, forms, uitableview

This week my mother (who is a beutician) asked me if I was able to create an iPhone app for her. I tried messing around with Xcode a number of years ago but it was nothing more that messing around.
I said I would give it a go, as I am her loving son, haha. I am a COMPLETE noob to all of this, but yet so far I have been able to work through and problems ive come across until now (thanks to Google).
Basically, I am trying to create a form that allows a user to fill out and send an appointment request that is submitted through my website to a php file using the mail() function, which is then sent to my mothers email.
So far so good.

[a screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy5XN.png)

If I fill out the First name, last name, email and contact number, they all send fine. My problem is finding a method of sending the name of the desired treatment along with the rest of the information.
As there are a lot of treatments they can choose from, I wanted users to be able to click on the treatment cell and choose the desired treatment from a TableView.
To be quite honest, I don't even know where to start. Ill attach my project in case anyone want to have a look, and if anyne can figure this out (its probably a dead sinch for you guys) ill be very grateful.
I don't mind if you test the email function through my php file. The emails will still come to me however. I cant go lending out my server details unfortunately.

My other problem which I haven't really looked at is choosing a date and time, like in the Apple clock app when choosing an alarm, but thats a problem I can solve later.

Heres the project.
http://theomnicraft.com/delta.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a UIPickerViewer for selecting a treatment and a UIDatePicker for the date/time.

You just need to implement a few basic methods for both of them that initialize the objects with some values, and then save the selection when a cell is selected.

Reference (Date Picker): http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DatePicker/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

Reference (Picker Viewer):
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPhone_UIPickerView_Example_(Xcode_4)

If you have gotten this far, you can probably follow some of the tutorials you will find on Google or Youtube and be able to implement this.

To implement this inside the tableview, you will need to make some small changes to your tableview's cellForRowAtIndexPath method. You will need to check when you are in the 2nd section of the table and are displaying the first cell, to have the input field link to a PickerViewer rather than the standard text input field, and the datepicker for the 2nd cell (based on your screen shot).

This example should help: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html